# Why is the sigmoid of a linear model equal to the probability of the target being $1$?

Tags: logistic-regression

From [this](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/logistic.html) resource, the writer starts with a linear model:

$$
y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + ... + \beta_m x_m
$$

and then makes the RHS sigmoidal. This must then make the LHS sigmoidal to preserve the equality.

$$\implies S(y) = S(\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + ... + \beta_m x_m) = \frac{1}{1+ \exp^{-(\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + ... +\beta_m x_m)}} $$

But he instead writes

$$
P(y=1) = S(\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + ... + \beta_m x_m)
$$

Could someone explain the implication that $S(y) = P(y=1)$?

Comment: I don't think it should be thought of as applying an operation to both sides and having it result in a probability. Instead, I think it's just a different choice of model which, with output in $(0,1)$, *can* be used to model probabilities. I think the author is providing motivation, not a derivation. See if this source is more clear: https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/uADA/12/lectures/ch12.pdf

Comment: @Joe Is there no other manner of mysticism justifying why logistic regression deals in probabilities other than the fact that it *can* purely because its range is confined to the range with which probabilities are measured?

Comment: I believe that it is just a modeling assumption, but that it has other nice properties, such as when using MLE on a sample of data that are independent observations, the likelihood function factors nicely because it's a product of exponentials, and results in the cross entropy loss function which is convex. But I haven't seen that derivation in a while, so I'm not sure about that. Informally, I believe it is considered somewhat consistent to model probabilities with logistic regression, but I don't think there's a rigorous justification for it. Probably search/ask on cross validated for more.

Comment: Here's a related post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71176/intuition-behind-logistic-regression